# New line in paragraph key binding

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I suppose the way to insert a new line in a paragraph is just to press enter. This is not working for me and when I press enter The result is that I exit edit mode in paragraph. How can I do to enter a new line?

I think there is a configuration to choose what ener does in paragraph mode, how can I configure this?

Comment: On my Mac CS6 version, Enter will always leave edit mode, and Return will create a new paragraph and shift-Return a linefeed. Return and Enter are not the same key.

Comment: @AAGD You should post that as the answer, because it **is* the answer :) Mac/PC makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac CS6 version (and likely on all others), `Enter` will always leave edit mode, `Return` will create a new paragraph and `shift-Return` a linefeed. `Return` and `Enter` are not the same key.

Comment: There is no distinction between Enter and Return on PC... Or otherwise pls explain which is which on PC

Comment: It depends on your keyboard. Laptops often have only one key for both and you need to press an additional function key to switch. Extended keyboards usually have the enter key on the bottom right of the number block. Pls Google or RTM for more info...

Comment: @Paolo For some people broken preferences seem to be a source for this problem. Resetting prefs and a restart might help. Read: http://www.clearps.com/photoshop-forum/index.php/t/68675/